# Please explain this .htaccess file detaily

Tags: apache, .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on # I know it will make RewriteEngine on.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f # So, what is it?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d # So, what is it?
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L] # So, what is it?
```

#### [Pastebin Link](http://pastebin.com/rk0Z7Jpt)

Comment: what specifically don't you understand?  What don't you understand about it?  As the question stands right now it is very unclear.

Comment: I already got my answer by Joe.

Comment: Thank you Notulysses, Actually I am a new Stack Over Flow user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks very much like the rewrite rules for Drupal.  Pretty straightforward:

Turn on the rewrite engine

```
RewriteEngine on
```

If the URI provided does not point to an actual file

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
```

Or a directory

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Then pass the entire URI to the index.php script

```
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```